# Filling a blank JSON value from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Hello I am a little stuck on a part of my code and I'm not sure what avenue I can take in order to proceed.

I am trying to fill/update the json value (phone number) by running it past a js object I created with a list of phone numbers. I have successfully been able to get JSON (onCall) to match my list of phone numbers, however I'm unsure **how** to bring the phone number from the list over into the json file as an update.

Any Pointers?

```
var onCall = require ('../../data/json/amion.json');
    //outputs: 
    //  {
    //   "service":"ETC_Cardiology",
    //   "name":"Doe, John",
    //   "shift":"7a-7a",
    //   "cell":"blank"
    //   }, ..etc

var list   = require ('../../data/list/etc_cards.js');
    // outputs:
    //    var obj = [
    //        {
    //          "name": "Doe, Jane",
    //          "number": "‭(123) 456-7890‬"
    //        },
    //        {
    //         "name": "Doe, John",
    //         "number":"222-333-1234"
    //        },...etc

//--------------------------

console.log(fillCell());

function fillCell(){
    for (var myKey in onCall){
        if (onCall[myKey].cell =="blank"){
            for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
                if (onCall[myKey].name == list[i].name){
                    return 'Match! ('+myKey+'): '+onCall[myKey].name+' : '+list[i].name+ ' | ' +onCall[myKey].cell+' : ' +list[i].number;
                } else {
                    onCall[myKey].name == list[i++].name;
                }  
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: To be sure, you want to update amion.json from phone numbers provided in etc_cards.js ? In Node.js or in Javascript (in browser) ?

Comment: Adventurous of you to assume no two people share the same name.

Comment: I’d like to bring etc_cards phone number over into amion.json to fill in it’s blank cell number. I’d like to do it in node.js, on the server end